# libopencv_java4.so: incompatible target

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I'm new to android and android-studio. I'm facing to this error :

libopencv_java4.so: incompatible target

I build opencv with opencv_contrib myself for abi-armeabi-v7a and abi-x86_64.
There is java code and c++ code in my project. I copied code from [opencv tutorial](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing/jni)

What should I check to remove this error?

When I use option compiler --scan full ouput is :

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature. To report a bug, see https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html
Support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature. To report a bug, see https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html
External native generate JSON debug: building json with force flag false
External native generate JSON debug: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 21 for ABI ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON debug: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 21 for ABI ARM64_V8A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON debug: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 21 for ABI X86 and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON debug: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 21 for ABI X86_64 and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON debug: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON debug: JSON generation completed without problems
External native generate JSON release: building json with force flag false
External native generate JSON release: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI ARM64_V8A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI X86 and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\x86\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI X86_64 and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\x86_64\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: JSON generation completed without problems
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:opencv411:javaPreCompileRelease
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:opencv411:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:opencv411:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:opencv411:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:app:javaPreCompileRelease
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:generateJsonModelRelease
External native generate JSON release: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI ARM64_V8A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI X86 and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\x86\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: using platform version 21 for ABI X86_64 and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON release: JSON 'F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\x86_64\android_gradle_build.json' was up-to-date
External native generate JSON release: JSON generation completed without problems
:app:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build mixed_sample x86_64
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mixed_sample.dir/jni_part.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86_64\libmixed_sample.so
Build mixed_sample x86
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mixed_sample.dir/jni_part.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86\libmixed_sample.so
FAILED: F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libmixed_sample.so 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && F:\Data_SDK_Android\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=i686-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=F:/Data_SDK_Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=F:/Data_SDK_Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libmixed_sample.so -o F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86\libmixed_sample.so CMakeFiles/mixed_sample.dir/jni_part.cpp.o  G:/Lib/install/opencvandroid18/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so -ljnigraphics -llog -ldl -lz -latomic -lm && cd ."
F:/Data_SDK_Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: G:/Lib/install/opencvandroid18/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so: incompatible target
F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/src/main/jni/jni_part.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to 'cv::FastFeatureDetector::create(int, bool, cv::FastFeatureDetector::DetectorType)'
F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/src/main/jni/jni_part.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to 'cv::noArray()'
F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/src/main/jni/jni_part.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
:app:externalNativeBuildRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process F:\Data_SDK_Android\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\x86 --target mixed_sample}
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mixed_sample.dir/jni_part.cpp.o
  [2/2] Linking CXX shared library F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86\libmixed_sample.so
  FAILED: F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libmixed_sample.so 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && F:\Data_SDK_Android\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=i686-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=F:/Data_SDK_Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=F:/Data_SDK_Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libmixed_sample.so -o F:\Android-project\ListeCapteur\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86\libmixed_sample.so CMakeFiles/mixed_sample.dir/jni_part.cpp.o  G:/Lib/install/opencvandroid18/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so -ljnigraphics -llog -ldl -lz -latomic -lm && cd ."
  F:/Data_SDK_Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: G:/Lib/install/opencvandroid18/sdk/native/libs/x86_64/libopencv_java4.so: incompatible target
  F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/src/main/jni/jni_part.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to 'cv::FastFeatureDetector::create(int, bool, cv::FastFeatureDetector::DetectorType)'
  F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/src/main/jni/jni_part.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to 'cv::noArray()'
  F:/Android-project/ListeCapteur/app/src/main/jni/jni_part.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: I wrote a turorial/sample application for setting up native OpenCV 4.1.1 with Android on this [Github repository](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template). Hope it helps.

Comment: @vSomers (thanks) In your project  in settings.gradle there is : project(':opencv412').projectDir = new File('g:/lib/install/opencv/sdk') without this line my project cannot found import org.opencv. I don't understand because with new import module in android studio path to opencv is given. Can you give a link to a doc of this directive project?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question. With the instructions in the tutorial, you don't have to use the new Android Studio import module.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: It was not an issue but in your project with this line (https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template/blob/master/settings.gradle#L4) it solves all my issue. Where did you find this line in doc? my own project is https://github.com/LaurentBerger/neuralstyle

Comment: You can find instructions about this directive in the comment section of the `OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/build.gradle` file of the downloaded OpenCV Android SDK.